# GMAIL: EXPUNGE items in Trash

Tags: terminal, imap, openssl

I'm trying to empty my trash folder from terminal, but i'm not able to `expunge` any of the items present there.

Here are the steps that i've been following

```
> openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993 -crlf
> a001 login USER_NAME PASSWORD
> a002 select [GMAIL]/Trash
```

at which i get server response as

```
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $NotPhishing $Phishing)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $NotPhishing $Phishing \*)] Flags permitted.
* OK [UIDVALIDITY xxxxxxxxx] UIDs valid.
* y EXISTS
* a RECENT
* OK [UIDNEXT zzz] Predicted next UID.
* OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ bbbbbbb]
a002 OK [READ-WRITE] [Gmail]/Trash selected. (Success)
```

After this i've tried to delete one file (even though my goal is to delete all) using following commands

```
> a003 UID STORE zzz +FLAGS (\Delete)
a003 OK Success
> a004 UID EXPUNGE zzz
a004 OK Success
```

but no mail has been deleted from the trash folder. I've also tried by `turning auto-expunge off` and choosing `Immediately delete the message forever` under `When a message is marked as deleted and expunged from the last visible IMAP folder:` option.

I'm not able to find any documentation regarding the commands so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming from your previous question that `zzz` is the number referenced in `[UIDNEXT]`, that UID doesn't actually exist yet, and it is not an error to change flags of a non-existent message.

`UIDNEXT` represents the next UID expected to be assigned, it does not currently exist.  You can do a `UID SEARCH ALL` to get a list of currently assigned UIDs, or don't use UIDs at all: the message sequence numbers are `1:Y` (the number in the `EXISTS` response).

To delete all messages in Trash, first select the folder, than do:

```
a001 STORE 1:* +FLAGS (\Deleted)
a002 EXPUNGE
```

(Thanks @a1626 for correcting my STORE command)

Comment: can you elaborate on `1:Y` concept. I tried using `1` like we do for `fetch`, `EXPUNGE 1` but that threw error `BAD Could not parse command`.

Comment: Yes, the non UID version of EXPUNGE does not take an ID, it just expunges everything currently marked \Deleted.  When the `UIDPLUS` extension was defined, presumably they thought the more precise command would be more useful.

Comment: So i assume everything in Trash folder should already be marked \Deleted or will i need to do that? If yes, then how? and what will be the command to EXPUNGE ?

Comment: No, the Trash folder is just a folder, the messages look the same as any other folder.  You can mark _everything_ as \Deleted, if you really want to, with `STORE 1:* (\Deleted)`.  `1:*` means from message one to the end so is a shortcut for "everything".  Then you can do `EXPUNGE`.

Comment: What will be the command for `EXPUNGE`? `EXPUNGE 1:*` does not work.

Comment: 1 Small correct command to mark `deleted` will be `STORE 1:* +FLAGS (\Deleted)` instead of `STORE 1:* (\Deleted)`.

Comment: (Updates made to question)